# How to trigger GKE autoscaling decision on demand?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

The GKE autoscaling process makes what they call "decisions" about whether or not to autoscale. The logs will include details explaining why the process decided not to do anything (`noDecisionStatus`), which is cool. Search bait: This can also be seen as a notification with the text "Can’t scale up a node pool because of a failing scheduling predicate".

I've made some changes that should address the issues raised in the `noDecisionStatus` log entry. How do I get GKE to try making a decision again? It's been hours.

Comment: Same error. What changes have you made?

Comment: Various, in response to what Google suggests. Things like changing pod tolerations. I still have volume node affinity conflicts (which I totally expected and aren't an issue, lol, because of course there are conflicts) but I haven't dealt with them yet as I'm waiting to see if the other changes have any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I just had to wait. I'm seeing the `noDecisionStatus` logs again.